# Finding the probability distribtion of some values

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have a vector of $n$ values $([x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}])$. We know that $x_{i}=\frac{n}{i}, 1\leq i\leq n$. What are the steps to compute the cumulative distribution function of this vector?

Comment: If each coordinate assumes value $\frac{n}{i}$ then this vector is constant. If $x_i$ is the probability that a random variable assumes value $i$, you only have to ensure that the total mass is one. Otherwise, I don't think I understood your question.

Comment: @Daniel, the values are not constant. The value of each point is unique.

Comment: I believe the vector in OP is meant to be a weight vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize the vector so that its sum is equal to $1$. The current sum is given by

$$ S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n}{i} = nH_n$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number. A probability mass function is thus

$$ f(x_i) = \frac{x_i}{S} = \frac{1}{iH_n} $$

The cumulative mass function is

$$ F(x_i) = \sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac{1}{jH_n} = \frac{H_i}{H_n} $$